# Dealing with empty HTML tables generated from SQL tables

Tags: html, sql, sql-server

possibly a silly question.

I'm generating a HTML email based on changing tables in SQL server. I'm hitting an issue in that if any one of these tables are empty, the entire email is sent without any content.

I've attached the query I am using to populate the HTML fields for the email, I'm thinking the best method would be to add a case to insert a 'N/a' row into the table if there are no rows in the destination table, however I'm unsure of the code required for this.

Alternatively, any insight as to how I can code the HTML to deal with these empty tables would be useful.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Select code:

```
SELECT 
td = [Exercise],'',
td = [Weight],'',
td = [Set1],'',
td = [Set2],'',
td = [Set3],'',
td = [Set4],'',
td = [Set5],''

FROM [dbo].[Isolation_531]
```

Full code for this table:

```
 SET @tableHTML3 = 
N'<style type="text/css">
 #box-table
 {
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-align: center;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-top: 7px solid #9baff1;
 border-bottom: 7px solid #9baff1;
 }
 #box-table th
 {
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: normal;
 background: #b9c9fe;
 border-right: 2px solid #9baff1;
 border-left: 2px solid #9baff1;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #9baff1;
 color: #039;
 }
 #box-table td
 {
 border-right: 1px solid #aabcfe;
 border-left: 1px solid #aabcfe;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #aabcfe;
 color: #669;
 }
 tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color:#eee; }
 tr:nth-child(even) { background-color:#fff; } 
</style>'+ 
N'<H3><font color="Navy">Isolation Work</H3>' +
N'<H4><font color="Navy">This is isolation work based on last week. Feel free to change but try and focus on exercises appropriate to the workout day.</H4>' +
 N'<table id="box-table" >' +
 N'<tr><font color="Green"><th>Name</th>
 <th>Weight</th>
 <th>Set One</th>
 <th>Set Two</th>
 <th>Set Three</th>
 <th>Set Four</th>
 <th>Set Five</th>
 </tr>' +

 CAST ( ( 

SELECT 
td = [Exercise],'',
td = [Weight],'',
td = [Set1],'',
td = [Set2],'',
td = [Set3],'',
td = [Set4],'',
td = [Set5],''

FROM [dbo].[Isolation_531]

 FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
 N'</table>'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your @tableHTML3 string is made null when you attempt to concatenate a null value to it. There is a [feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx) to avoid this, but it will be deprecated in the future. It is best to code around it.

Use [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx):

```
...
CAST (ISNULL('<tr><td colspan="7">NO DATA</td></tr>',( 

SELECT 
td = [Exercise],'',
td = [Weight],'',
td = [Set1],'',
td = [Set2],'',
td = [Set3],'',
td = [Set4],'',
td = [Set5],''

FROM [dbo].[Isolation_531]

 FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
)) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) )
...
```

My html is a little rusty, but I think that's right. Feel free to update.

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for the comment. This is helpful, but I'm not quite sure where to place the isnull, replacing the cast ( ( results in a Implicit conversion from data type xml to varchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. Any thoughts?